# Scope or Isolate bootstrap styles to only under specific class or id?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack

I'm making a chrome extension that will overlay a react app inside the user content pages. I'd love to use bootstrap css inside of the root div for the app, but the bootstrap styles will affect the whole page.

Is there any way to scope bootstrap (short of editing the source myself) to a specific sub-element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another answer from my future self. I was able to achieve this in a React app by

`yarn install bootstrap`

This makes scss files available in the node-modules dir.

Then instead of importing the `bootstrap/scss/bootstrap` file, which looks like this:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.5.0 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2020 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2020 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

@import "functions";
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "root";
@import "reboot";
@import "type";
@import "images";
@import "code";
@import "grid";
@import "tables";
@import "forms";
@import "buttons";
@import "transitions";
@import "dropdown";
@import "button-group";
@import "input-group";
@import "custom-forms";
@import "nav";
@import "navbar";
@import "card";
@import "breadcrumb";
@import "pagination";
@import "badge";
@import "jumbotron";
@import "alert";
@import "progress";
@import "media";
@import "list-group";
@import "close";
@import "toasts";
@import "modal";
@import "tooltip";
@import "popover";
@import "carousel";
@import "spinners";
@import "utilities";
@import "print";
```

I made my own file `my_bootstrap.scss` and imported that. That file scopes all of the other imports to a class `.has-bootstrap`

```
.has-bootstrap {
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_functions";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_variables";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_mixins";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_root";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_reboot";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_type";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_images";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_code";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_grid";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_tables";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_forms";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_buttons";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_transitions";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_dropdown";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_button-group";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_input-group";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_custom-forms";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_nav";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_navbar";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_card";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_breadcrumb";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_pagination";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_badge";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_jumbotron";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_alert";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_progress";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_media";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_list-group";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_close";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_toasts";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_modal";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_tooltip";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_popover";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_carousel";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_spinners";
  @import "bootstrap/scss/_utilities";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me if you want to use some of the styles of bootstrap (assuming you have to use small amount of code of bootstrap in your app), then you can simply use that part of code from `bootstrap.css` file instead of importing whole file of bootstrap, because otherwise bootstrap file add style to whole `DOM`.